"Cannot find LICENSE in the plugin package." error when updating QGIS plugin
When trying to update a plugin of which I am the author, this message appears even though the LICENSE file is in the plugin folder and registered in the metadata.txt and until now, everything was working normally:

Plugin package: There were errors reading plugin package (please check
also your plugin's metadata). Cannot find LICENSE in the plugin
package. This file is required, please consider adding it to the
plugin package.

How can I be able to update my plugins again and upload new ones?

I uploaded an update yesterday with no issue, are you sure your zip file is valid - can you add a list of it's contents to the question

I am facing the same issue - the zip file contents are- the plugin.py, init.py,plugin_dialog.py, plugin_dialog_base.ui,plugin_upload.py, resources.py and metadata.txt. I also added the license.txt file after recieving this error. It doesnt seem to work. I have uploaded other versions of my plugin and have not had any license errors before.

It appears that the new requirement for a license file in a plugin mandates a license file called 'LICENSE' with no file extension - it doesn't like license.txt.

I have also run into this issue today when updating a plugin that I have updated many times before. I have a license.txt file in the plugin folder - I tried renaming it to LICENSE.txt just but got the same result.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
